# Save a file from the internet in a zipfile with jszip

Tags: javascript, node.js, jszip

I did a website to view 3d models and would like to have a option to download them, the download itself is working, however I'm struggeling to include the gltf file itself and have no idea how to do it.

This is the code so far, in the end the zip contains a gltf file, but it contains only the path to the file, not the file itself.

```
async function downloadModel(id) {
  const model = await this.fetchModel(id);

  var JSZip = require("jszip");

  var zip = new JSZip();
  zip.file("README.txt", "Text\nText");
  zip.file(model.name + ".gltf", model.file);
  zip.folder("textures");

  zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
    saveAs(content, model.name + ".zip");
  });
}
```

Comment: Well, what's the value and type of `model.file`?

Comment: It's a string containing the file path of the model

Comment: Well if it's just a string, then that's what JSZip is going to put in as content in the zip entry. JSZip can't know that that string is supposed to be a path of a (local?, remote?) file. If you want to put in the actual file-content, you have to load that file first and pass the actual file-content as second parameter to `zip.file(name, content)`

Comment: Oh, OK. Yeah its a local file. I'll try that then